# Firefox's document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top is incorrect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

When I ask Firefox version 17.0.1 for `document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;` on a simple site that has no styling at all, it returns the wrong value. I expect `8`, which is the browser default, but it gives me `21.4`. The `.left` offset however is correct.

In Chrome the offset is works fine and gives me `8` for both top and left.

I attached a Screenshot of the situation where you can see that the top shouldn't be `22.4.`[image: Screenshot of the situation]

Here's the HTML

```
<html><head>
<title>Index</title>
<style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Index</h1>
        <p>This is the index. The site contains in total 4 sites without
            any Javascript. They are linked using href links.</p>
        <p>The site looks like this:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Index ->; a</li>
            <li>Index ->; b</li>
            <li>b ->; c</li>
            <li>c ->; b</li>
            <li>c ->; Index</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="a.html">Go to A</a>
    <a href="b.html">Go to B</a>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Problem also occurs in Firefox 18.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving your `<html>` a yellow background and your `<body>` a green background and see what the rendering looks like.  I'll bet the green rectangle is in fact 22px from the top of the viewport.

The reason that happens is that the 8px top margin of the body is collapsing with the 22+px top margin of your `<h1>`, because those margins are adjacent.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Chrome has the same exact behavior in standards mode.  But in quirks mode (which his what the above HTML snippet is in), it seems to do something weird where the `<h1>` still reports a 21px top margin but this margin does not collapse with that of the `<body>`.. though putting a top margin on the `<div>` does collapse it with the body.  That's quirks mode for you.

Comment: You the man! Adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` in Chrome showed the problem. With the doctype declaration the `H1` moved down to a margin of `21`. It is however stupid that Firefox renders it like the margin is 8, but `document.body.getBoundingClientRect()` returns a different margin.

Comment: Uh... In what way does Firefox render it like the margin is 8?  The margin is in fact 21. Did you try adding the backgrounds as I suggested?

Comment: Whoops, I did that in Chrome. Now that I do, I see that Firefox indeed renders correctly. Chrome is the only one not rendering correctly without the `<!DOCTYPE html>`. My bad!

Comment: margin-collapse to the rescue? http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-margin-collapse

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried it using Firefox 18 with the following code and I get the expected value of 8 (I took out all your formatting for clarity but it gives the same value of 8 with it all in).

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("getBoundingClientRectTop").innerHTML = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="getBoundingClientRectTop">???</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, but not for me since I need to be able to run it from the console, not Javascript in the page. I use it with Selenium.